# How to listen for change in a collection?

Tags: java, spring, triggers, spring-data, dbf

I have to check for changes in an old embedded DBF database which is populated by an old third-party application. I don't have access to source code of that application and cannot put trigger or whatever on the database. For business constraint I cannot change that...

My objective is to capture new records, deleted records and modified records from a table (~1500 records) of that database with a Java application for further processes. The database is accessible in my Spring application though JPA/Hibernate with HXTT DBF driver.

I am looking now for a way to efficiently capture changes made by the third-party app in the database.

Do I have to periodically read the whole table and check if each record is still unchanged or to apply any kind of diff within two readings? Is there a kind of "trigger" I can set in my Java app? How to listen properly for those changes?

Answer (score 1):

There is no JPA mechanism for getting callbacks from a database when the data changes.

The only options is to build your own change detection. Typically you would start by detecting which entities were added, removed, and which still exists. For the once that still exist you will need to check if they are changed, so the entity needs an `equals()` method. 
An entity is identified by it primary key, so you will need to get the set of all primary keys, once you have that you can easily use Guava's `Sets` methods to produce the 3 sets of added, removed, and existing (before and now), like this.

```
List<MyEntity> old = new ArrayList<>(); // load from the DB last time
List<MyEntity> current = new ArrayList<>(); // loaded from DB now

Map<Long, MyEntity> oldMap = old.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MyEntity::getId, Function.<MyEntity>identity() ));
Map<Long, MyEntity> currentMap = current.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MyEntity::getId, Function.<MyEntity>identity()));

Set<Long> oldKeys = oldMap.keySet();
Set<Long> currentKeys = currentMap.keySet();

Sets.SetView<Long> deletedKeys = Sets.difference(oldKeys, currentKeys);
Sets.SetView<Long> addedKeys = Sets.difference(currentKeys, oldKeys);
Sets.SetView<Long> couldBeChanged = Sets.intersection(oldKeys, currentKeys);

for (Long id : couldBeChanged) {
    if (oldMap.get(id).equals(currentMap.get(id))) {
        // entity with this id was changed 
    }
}
```